# Which port for SMTP Mails

Tags: email, smtp

I am having an issue with my provider/hoster and I am looking for some advise.

We send Freeform forms with SMTP with this config. Looks like many others do the same.

```
$config['mail_protocol']    = 'smtp';
 $config['smtp_server']      = 'tls://smtp.gmail.com:465';   
 $config['smtp_username']    = 'mail@xxx.xx';
 $config['smtp_password']    = 'xxxxx';
 $config['email_newline']    = "\r\n";
 $config['email_crlf']       = "\n";
```

The sending goes on port 465 but Google recommends port 587. And port 587 is what our hoster wants us to send on. But EE can not.

Our hoster opened port 465 for us. When they do server updates the port gets closed again and we don't get any forms untill we realize and ask to get the port open again.

If we use port 587 we get this

```
Message: fsockopen(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL
Error messages: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong
version number
```

This leads to the question: does EE  try to do someting like this

```
openssl s_client -tls -crlf -connect smtp.gmail.com:587
```

or

```
openssl s_client -ssl3 -crlf -connect smtp.gmail.com:587
```

instead of what our hoster finds to be the right way

```
openssl s_client -starttls smtp -crlf -connect smtp.gmail.com:587
```

He gave us this link for a reading
http://blog.mailgun.com/25-465-587-what-port-should-i-use/

I just do understand a little of these thing and wonder if my hoster is right in saying EE has to send SMTP mails different than it does at the moment?

Or is our hoster not flexible enough? I know people on hosters that have no issues sending over port 465 all the time.

I appreciate some feedback on this.

Comment: I'll post this as a comment, as it's not really an answer to your question - and it's self-serving (as I'm the developer of this add-on): but have you considered using [Escort](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/escort) instead of messing with SMTP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SMTP port is set in your Admin > Email Configuration. TLS is specified with the [`email_smtp_crypto` system configuration override](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/general/system_configuration_overrides.html#email-smtp-crypto):

$config['email_smtp_crypto'] = 'tls';

With both of those in place, removing the protocol and the port from your server string should allow you to send via SMTP with those settings.

Comment: Thank you Derek, it seem to work now. The server string is
 $config['smtp_server']      = 'smtp.gmail.com'; and settings like you suggested